# template template variadic pack of concepts

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I have a collection of concepts:

```
template <typename type_t>
concept boolean_c = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<type_t>, bool>;

template <typename type_t>
concept integer_c = !boolean_c<type_t> && std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<type_t>>;

…

…

…

template <typename type_t>
concept number_c = std::is_floating_point_v<std::decay_t<type_t>>;

template <typename type_t>
concept string_c = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<type_t>, std::string>;
```

And I want a new concept that checks if a given type matches any concept of a given list of the previously defined concepts. So I guess that a template-template parameter is mandatory:

```
template <typename type_t, template<typename> class ... concept_pack>
concept any_of_c = (concept_pack<type_t> || ...);

template <typename type_t>
concept compatible_type_c = any_of_c<type_t, boolean_c, integer_c, number_c, string_c>;
```

I need the `compatible_type_c` to ve a variadic template because I'll use it to check `std::tuple`s and `std::variant`s. The code above does not compile:

```
<source>:17:45: error: expected ')'
concept any_of_c = (concept_pack<type_t> || ...);
                                            ^
<source>:17:20: note: to match this '('
concept any_of_c = (concept_pack<type_t> || ...);
                   ^
<source>:17:49: error: expected expression
concept any_of_c = (concept_pack<type_t> || ...);
                                                ^
<source>:20:46: error: too few template arguments for concept 'boolean_c'
concept compatible_type_c = any_of_c<type_t, boolean_c, integer_c, number_c, string_c>;
```

I wasn't able to write the `any_of_c` in a way that the compiler understands (I've tried with and without parenthesis and different placement of the elipsis) and the `compatible_type_c` asks for template parameter even if I've specified that it is a template.

How should I write the code in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: A concept is neither a class nor a class template. You cannot parameterise a template by a concept.